# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Unable to read file and encrypt it

Tags: vb.net, encryption, nullreferenceexception, filestream

I am new to VB.Net.
I am trying to read a text file, encrypt it and save the encrypted text file. However when I start the encrypt process, I get a System.NullReferenceException error.

```
Private Sub encryptOrDecrypt(ByVal strInputFile As String, ByVal strOutputFile As String, _
                           ByVal byteKey() As Byte, ByVal byteInitializationVector() As Byte, _
                           ByVal Process As CryptoProcess)

    Try

        'File stream for handling file IO
        fileStreamInput = New System.IO.FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        fileStreamOutput = New System.IO.FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        'Ensure that output file is empty
        fileStreamOutput.SetLength(0)

        'Declaring variables for encryption and decryption process
        Dim byteBuffer(4096) As Byte
        Dim bytesProcessed As Long = 0
        Dim fileLength As Long = fileStreamInput.Length
        Dim intBytesInCurrentBlock As Integer
        Dim csCryptoStream As CryptoStream

        Dim cryptoRijnadel As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged

        Select Case Process
            Case CryptoProcess.EncryptFile
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fileStreamOutput, _
                                                  cryptoRijnadel.CreateEncryptor(byteKey, byteInitializationVector), _
                                                  CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Case CryptoProcess.DecryptFile
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fileStreamOutput, _
                                                  cryptoRijnadel.CreateDecryptor(byteKey, byteInitializationVector), _
                                                  CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        End Select

        While bytesProcessed < fileLength
            intBytesInCurrentBlock = fileStreamInput.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 4096)
            csCryptoStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, intBytesInCurrentBlock)
            bytesProcessed = bytesProcessed + CLng(intBytesInCurrentBlock)
        End While
        csCryptoStream.Close()
        fileStreamInput.Close()
        fileStreamOutput.Close()

        If Process = CryptoProcess.EncryptFile Then
            Dim fileOriginal As New FileInfo(strFileToEncrypt)
            fileOriginal.Delete()
        End If

        Dim Wrap As String = Chr(13) + Chr(10)
        If Process = CryptoProcess.EncryptFile Then
            MsgBox("Done", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Done")
        End If

    Catch When Err.Number = 53
        MsgBox("File not found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Invalid File")
    Catch
        fileStreamInput.Close()
        fileStreamOutput.Close()

    End Try
End Sub
```

The debugger shows the error at the line `fileStreamOutput.Close()`

Please help.

Comment: Which `fileStreamOutput.Close()` line?  The one after the `While` loop or the one in the `Catch`?  I suspect the latter...

Comment: which one?  You close it multiple times which is likely the problem.  a USING block(s) would avoid that

Comment: @StevenDoggart The one in the 'Catch'

Comment: if you are catching an exception which happens BEFORE you create the stream it will be Nothing in the Catch.  a USING block will close **and** dispose of them for you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely the fact that the first line fails, so execution jumps to the `Catch` block before the `fileStreamOutput` variable gets set:

```
fileStreamInput = New System.IO.FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
fileStreamOutput = New System.IO.FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
```

The simplest solution would be to simply check if the variable is null before using it in the `Catch` block:

```
Catch
    If fileStreamInput IsNot Nothing Then
        fileStreamInput.Close()
    End If
    If fileStreamOutput IsNot Nothing Then
        fileStreamOutput.Close()
    End If
End Try
```

However, as Plutonix pointed out, a `Using` block would be simpler.  It's also worth mentioning that you are doing some other VB6-ish things in this code where better alternatives exist in VB.NET.  For instance, you are calling `MsgBox` rather than using the more functional `MessageBox.Show`.  However, that's very minor.  The most regrettable thing is your use of the `Err` object.  *That*, I must say, goes beyond a simple disagreement in preference.  *That* crosses the line into offending my sensibilities.  The proper way to catch exceptions in VB.NET is to specify the type of the exception in the `Catch` statement.  You should never use the `Err` object, ever.

```
Try
    Using fileStreamInput As New System.IO.FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Using fileStreamOutput As New System.IO.FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
            ' ...
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
    MessageBox.Show("File not found", "Invalid File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End Try
```

If, however, you choose to not use the `Using` blocks, you should, at the very least, change the last `Catch` to `Finally`.  Currently, it catches and eats all other exceptions, so if anything else goes wrong, nothing will know about it.

Comment: Now I am getting a System.UnathorizedAccessException. I am not able to save the output file to the location I have selected.

Comment: Yes, that's the exception I was most expecting that you would be getting.  It just means that the current user (the one under which your process is being run) doesn't have sufficient OS privileges of open that particular file.